# Kotlin parallel coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is it acceptable to save multiple job instances from separate coroutines. Let's say i want to run a couple coroutines at once in which they are unrelated and cannot happen in one coroutine but i want them to run parallel. In Android i should be saving the job instance so i can cancel the job in the onDestroy method. Would it be acceptable to save each job separately in a list or am i breaking some kind of rule. I know in RX they have Subscriptions why isn't there an equivalent in Kotlin Coroutines?

```
val jobList = arrayListOf<Job>()

fun startJob1() {
    jobList.add(launch {
        //do some work
    })

fun startJob1() {
    jobList.add(launch {
        //do some other unrelated work
    })

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    cancelAllActiveJobs(jobList)
}
```

Does this type of architecture make sense for coroutines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manullay keep a list of `Job` objects that you launch, but you can also use a parent-child Job hierarhy that is available out-of-the box to manage and keep the list of launched jobs easier.

So, first, instead of a list of jobs, you define a reference to a parent job:

```
val job = Job()
```

Then, every time you lauch a new coroutine you make it a *child* of this job:

```
fun startJob1() {
    launch(job) { // make it a child
        //do some work
    }
}

fun startJob1() {
    launch(job) { // make it a child
        //do some other unrelated work
    }
}
```

Finally, when you need to destroy your object and cancel all the jobs you just cancel the parent job.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    job.cancel()
}
```

The advantage of this apporoach is that the list of jobs is managed automatically. New coroutines can be launched and added to the parent job and when they complete they automatically remove themselves from the parent job.

You can read more in the corresponding section of the guide: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#cancellation-via-explicit-job

Comment: This way you still have just one parent job at a time. My question is about having a list of parent job. I even gave an example of what I am questioning.

Comment: The code that I've provided in the answer does exactly the same as your original code. It sill runs multiple jobs, they are still kept in a list. Try it. The difference is that you don't have to explicitly manage this list, since all the jobs are children and parents automatically keeps their list.

Comment: Make sense, would it be possible to use the Job() context on UI thread.

Comment: You can use `launch(UI + job)`

Comment: How to accomplishe this with Anko Coroutine extensions?? we only need to use asReference() to avoid leaking data/context?

Comment: In this approach there's a way to cancel a specific coroutine? Something like giving a id and cancel that?

Answer (score 3):

That’s totally doable, and also nothing special. Look at this simple example which creates 100k jobs at once:

```
val jobs = List(100_000) { // launch a lot of coroutines and list their jobs
        launch {
            delay(1000L)
            print(".")
        }
    }
 jobs.forEach { it.join() }
```

For making the jobs cancellable, it must itself check if it has been cancelled from outside, which you can do with a loop over the activity state: `while (isActive)`.

Here's an example with two jobs that are cancelled afterwards:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val jobs = arrayListOf<Job>()
    jobs += launch {
        var nextPrintTime = startTime
        var i = 0
        while (isActive) { // check if still active
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= nextPrintTime) {
                println("Job1: Sleeping ${i++} ...")
                nextPrintTime += 500L
            }
        }
    }

    //another job
    jobs += launch {
        while (isActive) { // check if still active
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= 42) {
                println("Job2: Sleeping 42 ...")
                delay(500L)
            }
        }
    }
    delay(1300L) // delay a bit
    println("main: Cancelling the sleeping job!")
    jobs.forEach { it.cancelAndJoin() } // cancels the job and waits for its completion
}
```

Comment: i know it is doable but is it correct, is that how coroutines are suppose to be used? In android i will have to handle the states of each job and handling if a duplicate job is an error that i want to ignore or i should run it again

Comment: Yes absolutely. For making the jobs cancellable, it must itself check if it has been cancelled from outside, which you can do with a loop over the activity state: `while (isActive)`

Comment: You are saving all child jobs from the main coroutine and cancelling at the end of the function. Im more worried about saving multiple parent jobs, knowing when to cancel those and making sure duplicates do not exist. The parents will get cancel onDestroy. 2 very different things

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your question then